Definition of the determinant using Laplace expansion
Is there a method to define the determinant solely through Laplace expansion, for example, by
$$ \operatorname{det} A := \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i}a_{0i} \operatorname{det}(A_{0i}),$$
while still proving the standard properties, such as
$\operatorname{det} A^T = \operatorname{det} A$ and $\operatorname{det} A' = -\operatorname{det} A$, where $A'$ is obtained from $A$ by transposing two rows or columns?
In particular, I would be interested in an introduction to the determinant without having to consider permutations.

Yes this is done in some books, like Serge Lang's Linear Algebra. However permutations naturally arise at some point.
